# airflow UI not showing all DAG

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to use `apache airflow`.
I managed to install everything.

I added a new DAG into dag folder and when I run `airflow list_dags` it shows me the dag examples along with my new dag.

However, when I go to UI I can't see the DAG listed in DAG tab.

I already killed webserver and restarted everything. It didn't work

fyi, I'm running apache on a VM with centos7.

thanks.

Comment: Are your dags owned by airflow? Are you seeing any errors on the UI?

Comment: Not seeing any error. "dags owned by airflow", what you mean? the field owner in the args given to dag? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Are your dags owned by the user that runs airflow?

Comment: Also, I would recommend looking into the "Why isn't my task getting scheduled" here on https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html -- those steps may be able to help you!

Comment: Ok, I think @Zack got the point. I was creating a Dag with an Owner that doesn't exist in airflow. After creating user on Airflow, I can see the Dag in the UI

Comment: @MarcoFumagalli you should write the solution as an answer and accept it, for future reference, as other's will search for the solution of the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zack in the comment section is right. If you change the owner in the dag's argument from the default 'airflow' to something else i.e

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'whateveryournameis', <----
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('tutorial', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1))
```

in order to have your new dag shown in UI dags list, you should create a new user in airflow.
Creating a user is simple. Go to UI, under Admin, go to Users and create a new one.